# Moment of inertia of a rotating square toroid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, geometry, moment-of-inertia, inertia

I'm trying to work out the moment of inertia (i.e. what would be $I=mr^2$ for a point mass) of the volume of rotation around the y-axis of a square with side length *a*, at a radius along the x-axis *R*, and I'm having trouble understanding how to do so. At risk of making an XY-problem, it seems like I need to find what I can only describe as the "centre of inertia" (is this the area moment of inertia??), from which I can use the aforementioned point mass formula, but I'm reaching a roadblock of how to work out the former.

Comment: Doe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3397035/818925) answer your question? Also look at [equation 3 of this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0507172.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I may visualizing this wrong, but it sounds like your are looking for (I) for a solid cylinder with the center (of radius, R) cut out.  If true, I would find the (I) for the complete cylinder and then subtract the (I) for the part that was cut out.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the situation (generalized to a rectangle with sides $a$ and $b$)

[image: fig]

The mass moment of inertia about the axis of revolution is $I_{yy} = m R^2 + m \frac{a^2}{4} $

How is that? Take the integral to get

$$ I_{yy} = \rho \int_{-b/2}^{b/2} \int_{R-a/2}^{R+a/2} r^2 (2\pi r) {\rm d}r {\rm d}z $$

and use the density in terms of mass and volume $\rho = \frac{m}{V} = \frac{m}{2 \pi R a b}$

The rest is algebra.

The interpretation of $I_{yy}$ is that of all the mass on section center (radius $R$) is the $ m R^2$ term, and the remaining $\frac{m a^2}{4}$ term is due to the distribution of mass around the section center.